# com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapAttribute objectGUID wrong encoding

Tags: java, groovy, encoding, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to do a LDAP Search to an AD using Groovy, retrieving the following attributes: 'sn', 'givenName', 'sAMAccountName', 'memberOf', 'objectGUID'. Everything is displayed fine, except the objectGUID.

```
Code for LDAP Search:
```

```
import javax.naming.directory.*

// base OU for our search
GRP_OU = 'OU=cust,DC=example,DC=com'

mkCtx = {param = [:] ->
  new InitialDirContext(
    (Hashtable)param.collect { k, v ->
      [InitialDirContext[k], v.toString()]
    }.collectEntries()
  )
}

mkCtx(PROVIDER_URL: "ldap://example.com:389",
  INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY: 'com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory',
  SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION: 'simple',
  SECURITY_PRINCIPAL: "CN=user,DC=example,DC=com",
  SECURITY_CREDENTIALS: 'password',
).search(
  GRP_OU, '(&(mail=ldaptest@example.de)(memberof=group,DC=example,DC=com))', new SearchControls([searchScope: SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE])
).collect { entry ->
    def attributes = ['sn', 'givenName', 'sAMAccountName', 'memberOf', 'objectGUID']
    def newlst = []
    newlst = attributes.collect { entry.attributes.get(it) }
    println(newlst[0].toString().tokenize(': ')[1])
    println(newlst[1].toString().tokenize(': ')[1])
    println(newlst[2].toString().tokenize(': ')[1])
    println(newlst[3].toString().tokenize(': ')[1])
    println(newlst[4].toString().tokenize(': ')[1])
}
```

which provides the following output:

```
LDAPTest
LDAPTest
ldaptest
CN=user,OU=group,DC=example,DC=com
S�A|P2K��k6@(�
```

I already tested it without the `toString().tokenize()` function, but same result.

How can I parse the objetGUID to a readable String (e.g. objectGUID: x0880xx89-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-181969abcd8a)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following change in your code:

```
byte guidBytes[] = entry.attributes.get("objectGUID")
def guid = guidBytes.encodeHex().toString().replaceAll('^(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})', '$1-$2-$3-$4-')
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to parse it. 

now i hava a similar issue with the Base64 encoding of this GUID..

Comment: guidBytes.encodeBase64()